# how to merge two nested list of dict into new one

Tags: python, list, dictionary, merge

I have two nested list of dicts, like to merge with the same grouped key. For example:

DIC1:

```
{'SW-01': [{'Aip': '192.168.2.1',
        'Bip': '192.168.2.0',
       {'Aip': '192.168.3.3',
        'Bip': '192.168.3.2'}]}
```

DIC2:

```
{'SW-01': [{'Aip': '192.168.1.19',
            'Bip': '192.168.1.18'}],
 'SW-02': [{'Aip': '192.168.1.83',
            'Aip': '192.168.1.82',
           {'Aip': '192.168.1.85',
            'Bip': '192.168.1.84'}]}
```

How to merge two dict above, with group key?
Here is the code I have used tried to merge, but I get SW1 data twice from the DIC1 and DIC2.

```
    d = {}
    for key in (*dic1, *dic2):
        try:
            d.setdefault(key,[]).append(dic1[key])
        except KeyError:
            pass
        try:
            d.setdefault(key,[]).append(dic2[key])
        except KeyError:
            pass
    pprint(d)
```

Comment: Add whats the expected output and the result you're getting from your code

Comment: Write the expected result please

Answer (score 0):

Try to `list()` your dictionaries and then append two lists. `().append` does not support list operators